# Does clapping children on the back in certain positions help clear mucus from their lungs?

Tags: physiology, children

Chest Physical Therapy (CPT) is the practice of clapping children on the back to clear mucus out of the lungs.

- [FairView](https://www.fairview.org/patient-education/88975) (a Minnesotan non-profit health site) recommends it for chest infections.

  > Chest physical therapy (CPT) is a method for clearing mucus out of the lungs. Keeping the lungs clear helps your child breathe easier. CPT involves 3 main steps:
  >
  > - Putting your child in certain positions
  > - Clapping on the body
  > - Having your child cough
- [University of Michigan Health department](https://www.uofmhealth.org/health-library/ug1720) recommends "Postural Drainage and Percussion" to help children with Cystic Fibrosis.

  > Postural drainage and chest percussion (PD & P) is one of several airway clearance techniques that help clear mucus from your child's lungs.

This practice seems to be more or less spread depending on the country. For example, I have rarely heard of it in Italy or the USA, but it seems to be quite popular in France.

Mechanically it does not seem to make any sense to me: the density and viscosity of the mucus seems to be too large to allow for its displacement through percussion.

Are there studies supporting its use?

Comment: I am worried these are two different claims.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The claims that clapping (percussion of the chest) as an effective method to remove mucus:

- in *children with acute respiratory diseases* and in *adults with chronic obstructive pulmonary disease (bronchitis, emphysema)* **are not supported by quality evidence.**
- in individuals with *cystic fibrosis* **are supported by consistent evidence.**

### Children with acute respiratory diseases

[Airway clearance therapy in acute paediatric respiratory illness: A state-of-the-art review (South African Journal of Physiotherapy, 2019)](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6620562/):

> The use of any external percussion or vibration method is currently
>   **not supported** by high-level scientific evidence.

### Individuals with Chronic Obstructive Pulmonary Disease (COPD)

[Airway clearance in COPD: need for a breath of fresh air? A systematic review. (COPD, 2011)](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/21513439):

> The evidence for passive techniques such as postural drainage and
>   percussion is low.

### Individuals with cystic fibrosis

[Chest physiotherapy compared to no chest physiotherapy for cystic fibrosis (Cochrane, 2015)](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6768986/) (a review of evidence):

> One study (12 participants) reported increased radioactive tracer
>   clearance associated with all interventions compared to control,
>   although this was only reported to have reached significance for
>   postural drainage with percussion and vibrations.

[Pulmonary Function and Sputum Production in Patients With Cystic Fibrosis: A Pilot Study Comparing the PercussiveTech HF Device and Standard Chest Physiotherapy (Chest, 2004)](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0012369215321164?via%3Dihub):

> The PTHF *[PercussiveTech HF]* device appears to be a safe and
>   effective method of airway clearance in CF patients in this small
>   pilot study.